# How to insert checkbox form to database attribute of type set

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, forms

I have form content 4 checkboxes; my database MYSQL consist of two attributes (Id, courses)
the type of courses is set it's can have many items 
and I want to insert these checkboxes values to database

I am using this but it saves the last value of check ex: if I check to save C++, JAVA and vb save vb only!

```
INSERT INTO `$table` (`id`, `courses`) VALUES (NULL,'$ch');
```

$ch is variable save the name of the POST form value

How I can do this?

```
        <input type="checkbox" value="C++" name="c++" /> C++ <br />
        <input type="checkbox" value="JAVA" name="java" /> JAVA <br />
        <input type="checkbox" value="VB" name="vb" /> VB.NET <br />
        <input type="checkbox" value="PHP" name="php" /> PHP <br />


INSERT INTO `$table` (`id`, `courses`) VALUES (NULL, 'check1 , check2 , ... etc);
```

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how you tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us exactly what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. Give us a clear explanation of what isn't working and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). [Read](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) How to Ask a good question.

Comment: Checkboxes mean that you accept multiple values, so it also means you need to save multiple rows into the database. Group the checkboxes by name and then insert that many rows however you get checkboxes in the request.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$courses = [];
$i = 0;
if($_POST['c++'] != '')
{
    $courses[$i++] = $_POST['c++'];
}
if($_POST['java'] != '')
{
    $courses[$i++] = $_POST['java'];
}
if($_POST['vb'] != '')
{
    $courses[$i++] = $_POST['vb'];
}
if($_POST['php'] != '')
{
    $courses[$i++] = $_POST['php'];
}
$ch = implode(',', $courses); // It will convert the array ($courses) into comma separated string.
```

1. Here I have initialized a array $courses.
2. And if the checkbox is selected that means the value is not equal to null, then i have stored the value in $courses array.
3. At last i have change the array to comma separated string ($ch), which is suitable to store in database in courses column.